# ¿Cómo recibo los datos de un select multiple en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un `select multiple` que se llena dependiendo de los datos de otros `select`, el caso es que quiero mandarlo por medio de `ajax` a un archivo `php` para hacer una comunicación con la base de datos, el caso es que yo para tomar los datos del formulario utilizo `$("#").serialize()` entonces, no sé como recibir los datos por `php`, sí alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradezco.

`JQuery Ajax`

```
function enviarRegistro(){
        if(validarCampos()){
            var datos = $("#formRegistro").serialize();
            $("#pageLoader").fadeIn("fast");
            if($("#checkinput").prop("checked")){
                $.ajax({
                    data: datos,
                    url: '/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=guardarHasta',
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response){
                        var html;
                        if(response.trim() != "1"){
                            html = "<h4> No se han podido insertar "+ response.trim() +" registros</h4>";
                            $("#respuesta").addClass("alert-danger");
                            $("#respuesta").html(html);
                            $("#pageLoader").fadeOut("fast");
                            $("#respuesta").fadeIn("slow");
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $("#respuesta").fadeOut(2000, function() {
                                    $("#respuesta").html("");
                                    $("#respuesta").removeClass("alert-danger");
                                    });
                            }, 2000);
                        }else{
                            $("#respuesta").addClass("alert-success");
                            html = "<h4> Se ha insertado correctamente </h4>";
                            $("#respuesta").html(html);
                            $("#pageLoader").fadeOut("fast");
                            $("#respuesta").fadeIn("slow");
                            $("#empleado").val(0);
                            $("#nota").val("");
                            llenarEmpleados();
                            $("#errores").fadeOut("slow");
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $("#respuesta").removeClass("alert-success");
                                $("#respuesta").fadeOut(2000, function() {
                                    $("#respuesta").html("");
                                    });
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

`HTML`

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-size="6" data-live-search="true" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
                        <option value="0" disabled>Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay que tener en cuenta que la función `serialize()` de **JQuery** te devuelve un `string` que luce similar a una cadena pasada por `get` en la **URL**. Ejemplo:

```
"frutas=platano&frutas=fresa&frutas=manzana"
```

Esta cadena no es un **JSON** por lo que el `type` que has definido en la llamada **AJAX** no es el adecuado. Además de que **JSON** no se trata de un formato que nos sirva en nuestro caso, ya que nosotros tenemos múltiples campos como la misma `key` y este no nos lo permite tener.

Es por ello por lo que te propongo usar la función `serializeArray()` en vez de `serialize()`.

**Ejemplo de conversión del select multiple a array:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="frutas[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">platano</option>
    <option>fresa</option>
    <option selected="selected">manzana</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input name="verdura" type="text" value="lechuga">
</form>
 
<script>
  function enviarRegistro() {
    var array = $( "form" ).serializeArray();
    console.log(array);
  }
  
  enviarRegistro();
</script>
```

**Ejemplo de llamada envío AJAX usando el array conseguido mediante serializeArray()**

```
function enviarRegistro() {
  var datos = $("#formRegistro").serializeArray();
  console.log(datos);
  $.ajax({
    data: datos,
    url: '/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=guardarHasta',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response){
      //Lo que quieras hacer tras recuperar la respuesta del servidor
    }
  });
}
```

Luego desde **PHP** lo único que tendrías que hacer es recuperar de `$_POST` los datos enviados:

```
$frutas = $_POST['frutas'];

print_r($frutas);
```

Comment: Una duda, qué efecto le daría a los otros datos del formulario, ya que te `input's` y `select's` normales

Comment: El mismo, se añadirían al `array` resultante. He añadido un `<inpyt type="text">` a mi ejemplo ejecutable para que puedas ver el resultado.

Comment: Interesante, gracias voy a aplicarlo a ver como me va

Comment: Amigo, no más me toma el ultimo valor que llega

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el nombre de `<select>` múltiple para indicar que se trata de un `array`. Ejemplo: `<select name="frutas[]" multiple="multiple">`.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste mucho

Comment: ¡Me alegro, un placer! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Para recoger los multiples valores de un select necesitas enviar el `array` de los datos seleccionados usando el name del campo del formulario.

```
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-size="6" data-live-search="true" id="empleado" name="empleado[]" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="0" disabled>Seleccionar empleado</option>
 </select>
```

Simplemente el name del campo será `empleado[]`.

```
var values = $(select).serialize();
console.log (values);
```